# Why am I calculating the wrong local position for the bottom of a sprite in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am creating a simple routine that performs an action when a GameObject falls below the bottom of a sprite. I've figured out how to get the dimensions of the sprite using bounds, but when I calculate where I think the bottom of the sprite is, it's returning a smaller number than I'd expect.

My method is as follows (the position of the sprite, minus the size of the bounds (half the width), should give me the bottom of the sprite?):

```
public class FooBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer ChildSprite;

    void Start()
    {
        float bottomEdgeInLocalSpace =
            ChildSprite.gameObject.transform.localPosition.y - ChildSprite.bounds.extents.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: using the Debugger is what you should be doing.. also how can anyone determine where you are going wrong in regards to your calculation(s) when you only post `1` line of code..

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, it's wherver the pivot point is on the mesh.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Doesn't the transform.position only give my the center of the object? I'm looking to calculate the position of the very bottom edge of the sprite itself.

Comment: @MethodMan I've updated the code example to provide context - I felt, obviously incorrectly!, that the explanation and the single line would be enough for a much more seasoned unity developer than myself to spot what turned out to be a world/local space mis-match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that [Renderer.bounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) is in world space, and I was working in local space, so directly applying it to the local position was giving me my nonsensical result.

By converting `bounds.min` to local space using [InverseTransformPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html), I was able to get the expected bottom of the sprite using the following:

```
float position = transform.InverseTransformPoint(symbol.bounds.min).y;
```